# Values are not displayed on the omniscript for multiselect element using custom value

Tags: apex, class, omnistudio, omniscript

I have a multiselect element on the omniscript and I am keeping the source as custom and calling an apex class. The problem is that the values are not getting displayed.

Apex Class:

```
    global class PicklistOptions implements omnistudio.VlocityOpenInterface {

    public Boolean invokeMethod(String methodName,
                                Map < String, Object > input,
                                Map < String, Object > outMap,
                                Map < String, Object > options) {

        if( methodName.equals('AccountNames') ){
            List < Map < String, String >> UIoptions = new List < Map < String, String >> ();
            
            for(Account acc : [Select Id, Name from Account]){
                Map < String, String > tempMap = new Map < String, String > ();
                tempMap.put('name', acc.Id);
                tempMap.put('value', acc.Name);
                
                UIoptions.add(tempMap);
            }
              
            outMap.put('options', UIoptions);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new omniscript and added the multiselect element with custom values from the same apex class and I was able to load the new values.